# How to store full tpl file in variable in open cart

Tags: php, opencart

I am working in open cart. Some of common file like header,footer etc which are stored in a variable is define by all file syntax.`echo $footer`
so I want to know location of file where this variable define I have checked all controller file in common folder but nothing found tell me process of store file in variable.

Answer (score 1):

Lets use common/home as an example. This will be the controller file located at `catalog/controller/common/home.php`.

First off, the footer template file is intended to be used as a page component and not an independent web page. The way we can tell this is by taking a peek at the footer controller file located at `catalog/controller/common/footer.php`. If you look towards the bottom of the index function you can see that rather than setting the output for a webpage the footer controller merely returns the loaded template/view file for `footer.tpl`.

Now back in the `home.php` controller file you can locate a line that reads `$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');`. What this line does is loads the footer template file into the associative `$data` array in the home controller. (Just as a note, in OpenCart if a controller is loaded with no specific function specified ie: `common/footer`, then the index() function is called by default). So as a result `$data['footer']` is now equal to what is returned by the index() function in `common/footer` controller.

In OpenCart the way that PHP variables are handed off to .tpl files is via the `$data` array formed in the controller file. You can look in to the specifics of how this works but they easy way to visualize it is to look towards the bottom of the home controller index() function at the line that reads `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/home', $data));`. You can see that the `common/home` .tpl/view file for the home page is loaded and the second argument in the `$this->load->view` function is the pre-formed associative `$data` array.

So, lets hop over in to the .tpl file for `common/home` located at `catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/home.tpl` and navigate to the bottom where we read `<?php echo $footer; ?>`. This is echoing the value in the home controller's `$data` array with the index "footer".

`$data['footer']` in the home controller file == `$footer` variable in the home template/view file

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge full information, header/footer file load in home file in $data variable so my question is tell use of home file and where is define and working of home file